# cakePHP + php5-fpm + memcached = lots of open TCP connections to memcached?

Tags: cakephp, tcp, nginx, memcached, php

I'm pretty sure this is a CakePHP bug, but figured someone here may have run across this and know how to fix. FYI - I've created a [ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/1705-cake-138-memcacheengine-does-not-close-connection).

I run PHP as fastcgi under nginx via php5-fpm. When I use 'Memcache' as the engine for my cake cache, I notice that TCP connections are not closed.  I notice that cake's [MemcacheEngine](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/memcache-engine/#line-198) does not ever call PHP [memcache::close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.close.php).

For people who run PHP under non-fastcgi processes, I think this is OK as at the end of the PHP request the process ends, and "breaks" the TCP connection between PHP and memcached.

Using php5-fpm this is not the case, as the PHP process stays running to be re-used.

Does anyone know a best practice for this?  I'm thinking of modifying the CakePHP code to close the connection at the end of processing - but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Note: CakePHP's MemcacheEngine does NOT use [pconnect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.pconnect.php).

My version info:

```
Ubuntu 10.10 64bit
PHP 5.3.3
PECL memcache 3.0.5
memcached 1.4.5
cakephp 1.3.8
```

Comment: Hwo many fastcgi worker processes are you seeing, and how many connections to memcache? Are you getting the same worker opening multiple connections instead of reusing its existing connection?

Comment: I use pm = dymamic for FPM so the child processes change.  After figuring out that MemcacheEngine uses addServer() I was able to verify that the workers connections to memcached were indeed being re-used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out MemcacheEngine uses [Memcache::addServer()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php) which by default uses persistence.  It is correctly re-using the connections between my FPM children and my memcached pool.

Cake has added a 'persistent' option now, to allow the overriding of the default behavior for those that wish:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1705-cake-138-memcacheengine-does-not-close-connection